# Jenkins CascadeChoiceParameter not rendering from Jenkinsfile

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

The following CascaseChoiceParamater code in a Jenkinsfile does not render a reactive parameter. Same code renders fine using a Jenkins pipeline script. (where it was successfully tested). Any ideas?

[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
name: 'TARGET_HOST',
choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
description: 'Target Server',
filterLength: 1,
filterable: false,
randomName: 'choice-parameter-38222740232420',
referencedParameters: 'ENV',
script: [
$class: 'GroovyScript',
fallbackScript: [
classpath: [],
sandbox: false,
script:
"return['Nothing']"
],
script: [
classpath: [],
sandbox: false,
script:
'''if (ENV.equals("PROD")) {
return ["RXBK1","RXBK2","ALL"]
}
else if (ENV.equals("UAT")) {
return ["RXDV1","RXBK1UAT","RXBK2UAT","ALL"]
}
else if (ENV.equals("QA")) {
return ["RXDV1","RXBK1QA","RXBK2QA","ALL"]
}
else if (ENV.equals("DEV")) {return ["RXDV1"]
}
'''
]
]
],

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KZNj.png)

Comment: Please share your Jenkinsfile. Declarative pipeline syntax not support `CascadeChoiceParameter` in `parameters{}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.